# Why won't my PosgreSQL database connect in my Node.js backend

Tags: node.js, postgresql, express, knex.js

Building my first Node/Express application and I can't pull the data from postgres.

This is the connection in server.js

```
var db = require('knex')({
      client: 'pg',
      connection: {
        host : '127.0.0.1',
        user : '',
        password : '',
        database : 'mydb'
      }
    });
```

the table is set up

```
mydb=# \dt
           List of relations
 Schema |   Name    | Type  |   Owner   
--------+-----------+-------+-----------
 public | paintings | table | me
(1 row)
```

this is the route

```
app.get('/crud', (req, res) => main.getTableData(req, res, db))
```

and this is the controller in main.js

```
const getTableData = (req, res, db) => {
  db.select('*').from('mydb')
    .then(items => {
      if(items.length){
        res.json(items)
      } else {
        res.json({dataExists: 'false'})
      }
    })
    .catch(err => res.status(400).json({dbError: `db error`}))
}
```

I'm hitting the 'db error' every time. What is missing here and/or how do I debug it?

EDIT: The error is saying 'mydb' doesn't exist.

Comment: log out the error when you catch it .catch(err => console.log(err)) to see what  is happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Log out the error by doing `.catch(err => console.log(err))`

My guess is that the table name is wrong and `from('mydb')` should probably be `from('paintings')`, since that's your table name.

On another note. You can do

```
const getTableData = (db) => {
  return (req, res) => {
    db.select('*').from('paintings')
      .then(items => {
        if(items.length){
          res.json(items)
        } else {
          res.json({dataExists: 'false'})
        }
      })
      .catch(err => res.status(400).json({ dbError: `db error` }))
  }
}
```

And make your route be like

```
app.get('/crud', main.getTableData(db))
```